# how to temporary use a font with the same name as a local registered one (in "use")

Tags: delphi, fonts

I know how to register+notify and unregister+notify a font using Delphi.
But I want to know what can I do when I have a font which has a similar name with a already registered font (but it's a different version). Maybe even in "use".
I can try one of these:

1. Use the font just locally in the program (but in some situations I don't have access to code because I didn't make it);
2. Somehow temporary unregister the local one (even if it was in "use"), use the new one as long the program is open and reregister the local one after the program is closed.
   I would prefer the first but I'm not sure 100% that it can be done (I never heard of a font used locally in a normal Windows program but I asked just in case I'm wrong).
   And I don't know if it's ok to forcibly unregister fonts in "use" (if it's possible).
   But maybe someone has a better idea...
   Thank you.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund Oh, I saw just now that the name was changed also. In the original name (in "use") was meant for the current local font but now I don't know if it makes much sense. But I trust you to know better english than me. Thank you.

Comment: if you're talking about my edit I only introduced a line brake before the `1.` so SO shows it as numbered list. The `edited [time]` is a link, click in `[time]` and SO shows you a page explaining what was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about telling the user he has an old version of the same font installed, and new versions needs to be installed so he can experience the new glyphs.

You can even do that in the installer for your program; that's what installers are for: people expect things to change/improve when running installers :)

*Edit:*

If you don't have an installer, then make it clear to the user that he has two options:

- have it let your app install the updated fotn
- don't see all the characters

Comment: Could be a solution, yes... I don't have installers, the programs are portable (started directly from USB stick/key/pen).

Comment: @John, if you really, truly want your app to work from a removable device (USB stick) you'll need to work around user's configuration, not change it. In your specific case I'd simply use Arial as it contains all glyphs and only use the older versions of `Ş` and `Ţ`, not the ones produced by the vista+ RO keyboard. But the real fix, as Jeroen suggests (+1), is to use an installer. At a minimum create a "Requisites Setup" that only deals with upgrading operating system components.

Comment: @Cosmin Yes, You're right but the problem with these program is that the user chooses which font to use so I have to install them all (not just Arial). And I will think about the installer. Oh, and each of you got +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Applications that change entire system settings for their own purposes, even if temporary, are typically looked at in a negative way.

Say you remove a font, then change it to yours, then your program ends/crashes before the original is restored.

Sounds like you have a variant font you want to use for your application that already uses a name
that may be found on the system.

I personally would change the name of your new font to something unique enough that it won't conflict with existing fonts.     That way you can use your font without affecting other applications.

**Updated:**

Since you can't change the name of the font.   I would follow Jeroen Pluimers Recommendation of asking if the user wishes to upgrade.   This does not need to be done in an installer, it could be done from the application on start up.    But asking the user is far better than doing it silently.

Comment: I just asked and I know already that it's not 100% ok to do this... It was just a possibility, not a sure thing. That's why I asked for a better idea. And, by the way, it's not a "variant font", it's multiple fonts at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ec6f335-c3de-44c5-a13d-a1e7cea5ddea&DisplayLang=ro made by Microsoft for Romanian language. So I can't change their names.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use font locally - bordering on the impossible

Your point "1" should be possible (use a given font only locally) because Web Browsers do it. The `@font-face` CSS directive can be used in a way to ignore the locally installed fonts. But I suspect doing this the web-browser way is difficult: I didn't see any way to [CreateFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using a TTF file. I suspect web browser do it by re-implementing the whole text rendering engine. This is very likely because they usually support more then one type of font files.

If you do get this to work, it's not going to work with standard API's. You're not going to set the `Font` property on a label and automatically get it to render using the given "local" font. You're definitively not going to get this working with an unmodified application.

#### Replace Windows font - very bad idea

Unfortunately, as Robert mentions, this is not something you should do. If the user happens to have a font with the *exact* name of your font, what makes you think yours is better? In this unlikely case you should use whatever the user has, and blame it on the user if the user installed a bad font.

#### Possible solutions

- Use images in place of the special-typography text. Works for small amounts of fixed font size text.
- Put your text into a `TWebBrowser` and style it with `CSS` to use your local, alternative font.

Comment: Thank you. 1. It's about this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ec6f335-c3de-44c5-a13d-a1e7cea5ddea&DisplayLang=ro You'll know what I'm talking about because you're Romanian :D... Unfortunately not everybody has those fonts installed so when I'm trying to start a program from stick on that computer it doesn't display properly those characters... 2. If the fonts have the same name I'm checking if mine has higher version number. 3. It has to work with different programs + like I said sometimes I don't have access to code so I can't implement these suggestions...

Comment: @John, if that's the case, you can safely upgrade the user's fonts! Because you're not installing different fonts, they're the same fonts, from the same source, but with more glyphs implemented.

Comment: Ok then. But still there is the problem "font(s) in use". I don't know how to replace them safely and without restarting Windows...

Comment: @John, restart Windows if you must.

Comment: Yes, I know this is partially ok I guess but, don't get upset, I will still look for a solution to do this without restarting. One reason is that most users don't like these restarts and I can understand why. If I am absolutely sure that there is no other way then I will implement the restart.